# In java, don't understand that simple while loop(the sum of 1 to 6)

Tags: java

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int i=1,sum=0;
    
    while(i<=6) {
        sum+=i++; 
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
```

}

}

this is java eclipse code, and it prints 21 normally
But i don't understand that "sum += i++; " code.
I understood the meaning of that code as, 1+1 2+1 3+1 4+1 5+1 6+1  -> 2+3+4+5+6 -> 20.
How is that code calculated in a while loop? And why not ++i?

Comment: You need to read up about the pre and post increment operators.

Comment: Currently the calculation is basically `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6`.  *"And why not ++i?"* - When you change it to that, what happens to the result?

Comment: Right.  The value of `i++` in an expression is the value of `i`.  As a side effect, it also bumps the value stored in `i`, but the bumped value isn't part of the expression.  The value of `++i` in an expression is `i+1`.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is 21 because we add each iteration of the loop in the sum.
so at each verification if a number is less than or equal to <=6 we add each in the variable sum. so the increment is after verification and not make the post incrementention. #JAVA